# How can use Object.getOwnPropertyNames with this operator TypeScript

Tags: typescript, types, typeerror, this

```
class MyClass {
    private firstKey: string | null = 'Test';
    private secondKey: number | null = 123;
    private thirdKey: string[] | null = [ 'first', 'second', 'third' ];

    constructor( firstParam: string, secondParam: string[] ) {}

    destroy() {
        for ( const propertyName of Object.getOwnPropertyNames( this ) ) {
            this[ propertyName ] = null;
        }
    }
}
```

I got an error on this code `this[ propertyName ]` and the error message is:

```
Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type 'MyClass'.
No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type 'MyClass'.
```

How can solve this error? Especially that I can't give any type for `this` operator?

Comment: Even if you do solve this error, the code here is wrong because you are assigning `null` to all properties even though you explicitly stated that they are not nullable.

Comment: @apokryfos yes I want to reset all properties to null as this method destroys the instance of the class. Do you think there's a solution for this?

Comment: `this[ propertyName as keyof typeof this ] = null as any;` but it's not really a good solution. Using `as any` really is a red flag in most cases

Comment: @apokryfos I also think that I can improve the whole code, thank you for your efforts and your time.

Comment: Why do you need to "destroy"/destruct the class?